# How should I (or Should I) reply to 'Enjoy' mail?

Tags: politeness, email

I sent out a vacation mail to my office group. And a colleague of mine replied to the mail with "Enjoy!". Now Should I reply to this mail?. If yes what would be a proper response to this?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Enjoy!" is just common e-mail courtesy and generally doesn't need a response. If you feel the need to reply to the e-mail you should keep is just as succinct as theirs e.g. "Will do!".

Answer (score 0):

To reply or not is your prerogative.

You can simply state "thank you!". Select *"reply"*  and you can put the "thank you" in the subject line of the message after.....

```
          ..RE: Enjoy! - Thank you!, will do...or whatever.
```